# How to calculate offset based on latitude and longitude

Tags: formula

How to calculate offset for time zones if only latitude and longitude are known?

For example: longitude = -94.52021, latitude = 32.31827. Offset = -360

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates/16086964